# When I delete the oldest logs from a log file the logging api inserts the rest of the logs again

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have a log file on my linux server called demo.log from which the logging api gets the logs.

What I want to do is to delete the old logs from demo.log but when I do that the logging api uploads the rest of the logs back to GCP duplicating them.

I have tried to use code programmed in node and this linux command: **sed -i "1,10d" demo.log**

I have been able to delete the logs successfully but I can't get the logging api not to duplicate the remaining logs.

How can I delete the logs without duplicating them in GCP?

This is the configuration file that points to demo.log in /etc/google-fluentd/config.d

```
<source>
   @type tail
   <parse>
       # 'none' indicates the log is unstructured (text).
       @type none
   </parse>
   # The path of the log file.
   path /home/username/demo/src/demo.log
   # The path of the position file that records where in the log file
   # we have processed already. This is useful when the agent
   # restarts.
   pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/demo-log.pos
   read_from_head true
   # The log tag for this log input.
   tag demo-log
</source>
```

Comment: Your logger is using `tail`. When you change the log file, the file size is different (most likely smaller than the last update) so logging thinks it is a new file and uploads the entire file. In summary, do not touch files used for logging.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers, in the end what I am going to do is to use log rotation. In theory it should not duplicate the logs.

Comment: Please check [Logs are duplicated](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/troubleshooting#logs_are_duplicated) from official documentation, it can be that log rotation is already enabled or timestamp is not parsed properly.